# Recently tried to install drivers for AMD Radeon HD 6850 on Ubuntu 21.04 - issues post install and unable to solve by uninstalling

Tags: drivers, radeon, amd-graphics, 21.04, amdgpu

Any help and advice would be greatly appreciated.

I thought I should update AMD drivers (big mistake after everything I have read now)

My GPU is AMD Radeon HD 6850. I installed the drivers, and started having an issue where my chrome wouldn't render properly (see screenshots). This bug is the same in a number of applications, but I am unsure what not all of them, leading me to be confused at what is causing the issue.

If I disable hardware acceleration for chrome it fixes the issue, but not for other applications.
[https://i.imgur.com/sopPbS2.png](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H86wP.jpg)

I have tried uninstalling, reinstalling all installed packages and at every stage its the same. I would rather not have to reinstall everything from scratch but its beginning to look like an easier option.

Answer (score 0):

What driver are you using? The Radeon or the `amdgpu` driver?

```
lspci -nnk | grep -i vga -A3 | grep 'in use'
```

Did you install new drivers via the AMD website, or just an `apt-udate`?

Also this may seem silly but my 6850 sometimes needs a jiggle to make sure its fully connected.